# Getting Started (Tab) is Showing Blank - lightning Not Working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I joined a brand new salesforce implementation team and I have System Administrator rights (apart from CEO) but I am not able to perform or execute any activity in Lightning environment whilst I am able to do all such activities in Classic Environment. I tried to administer Lightning settings under "Getting started Tab" but Tab is displaying a blank page. How do I solve the issue?

Comment: Have you enabled yourself as as Lightning Experience user along with MyDomain, etc?

Comment: Can you check the browser console for any errors. Also which browser are you using?